# How to CAST a VARCHAR value to INT if the value is comma seperated

Tags: mysql

The MySQL database I am working with has a column with comma separated values similar to -

```
mysql> select * from performance;
+----+------------------+
| id | maximums         |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 10000RPM, 60KM/h |
|  2 | 5000RPM, 30KM/h  |
|  3 | 25mph, 3000RPM   |
|  4 | 200KM/h, 2000RPM |
+----+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to cast the numbers found in to their own INT columns.

```
mysql> select maximums,  
CASE WHEN maximums like "%mph%" THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(maximums, 'mph', 1) AS UNSIGNED) END AS mph_int, 
CASE WHEN maximums like "%KM/h%" THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(maximums, 'KM/h', 1) AS UNSIGNED) END AS kmh_int, 
CASE WHEN maximums like "%RPM%" THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(maximums, 'RPM', 1) AS UNSIGNED) END AS rpm_int 
from performance;
+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| maximums         | mph_int | kmh_int | rpm_int |
+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 10000RPM, 60KM/h |    NULL |   10000 |   10000 |
| 5000RPM, 30KM/h  |    NULL |    5000 |    5000 |
| 25mph, 3000RPM   |      25 |    NULL |      25 |
| 200KM/h, 2000RPM |    NULL |     200 |     200 |
+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I expect the output to show me the values as INTs in new columns, however am unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful - Are you trying to create separate columns like `max_mph`, `max_rpm` and so forth, then put the integer into the appropriate column? Or do you want one column with the int value and another with the units? Show an example of the 'right' outcome. Also, you show a query you tried, which is good, but you didn't say what happened when you ran it.

Comment: I do notice that each of your `CASE` statements only has one `WHEN` - so you may as well use `IF` instead. However, this may be a case where the problem is better solved in a programming language (or at least a stored procedure) - especially if you don't know how many comma-separated entries there will be.

Comment: Hey @Jerry - thanks for your comments. I've updated my question to include the table and output of what I've tried so far. Yes, essentially what I am trying to do is grab any numbers found and cast them as INT in to new columns with the appropriate column name based if the number precedes KM/h, mph and so on.

Comment: Thinking it through, as long as you have exactly two values in the maximums column every time, you can make a query that is somewhat readable that does this. I think regular expressions might be the best approach, since `mph_int` is defined as "the digits that come before 'mph'. Alternately you can define `mph_int` as "if the first half of the term has 'mph' use the number that comes before it, otherwise if the second half of the term has 'mph' use the number that came before it." So you need to `COALESCE` two tests like you have above, one applied to each half of the `maximums` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's give this a whirl, using the good ol'-fashioned blunt instrument approach. I am guessing that you only need this to work once, to convert an old, poorly-designed schema into something more workable. Given that, I have made no effort at elegance or performance.

(If you are not using this to fix your data schema, you should, because the pain you are experiencing now is only the beginning.)

First, we need to split the `maximums` value into two pieces and process them separately. The first half is:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`maximum`, ',', 1)
```

The second half is similar, but there is a stray space:

```
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`maximum`, ',', -1))
```

From here on, let's just always trim, in case there is variation in the data. Now we need to see if the first section has 'mph' in it, and if so capture the value as you did in your question (this is essentially like your example but operating on only the first part of the `maximum` value):

```
IF(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`maximum`, ',', 1)) LIKE '%mph', SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`maximum`, ',', 1)), 'mph', 1), NULL)
```

Let's name that chunk of code "mph test on first half". The mph test on the second half is almost identical, just using -1 as the index. Finally, we need to put the non-null value (if either) into the column using `COALESCE`. Once we create all six variations of the test, we end up with the following:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    COALESCE([mph test on first half], [mph test on second half]) AS mph_int, 
    COALESCE([kph test on first half], [kph test on second half]) AS kph_int,
    COALESCE([rpm test on first half], [rpm test on second half]) AS rpm_int
WHERE
    ...
```

Chances are you don't actually need to formally cast the string of digits into an integer; if you are inserting into a table with columns of those types, MySQL will cast the value for you.

Comment: As a side thought, I might replace `mph_int` and `kph_int` with a single column `max_speed`, and convert the mph into metric and then coalesce all four of the speed tests. Then you can in your client software express all speeds in mph or kph depending on a user preference.